# Link Data Models to multiple files

Tags: powerpivot

I created a file that imports multiple tables, and then I do several modifications and calculations with Power Pivot. The problem is that I want to use the final results, not only in that current workbook, but also in other workbooks.

So my question is, is there a way to link other excel files to that data model that I created and worked on?

Please note the data changes every day, so I am looking for a permanent connection.

Appreciate any help here.

Comment: At this time, Excel reports using Power Pivot models as a source must be in the same workbook. It sounds like that won't be the case in the new Power BI platform.  If you can manage to make a pivot table based upon the Power Pivot model with the data you need, you could do normal linked Excel spreadsheets with the table as the source rather than the model.

Answer (score 2):

if I understand you correctly you would like to access the PowerPivot model/measures that you have created in one xls file from within other xls files.

If so, the "core" vs. "thin" workbook approach might be what you are looking for. This approach works with Excel 2010 but not with Excel 2013 however and you will need a Sharepoint Server with PowerPivot for this to work.

The approach is described in Rob Collie's awesome PowerPivot blog:

http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2011/02/powerpivot-scheduled-refresh-pt-3-thin-workbooks/

and here:

https://pivotstreamllc.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201148566-Splitting-Workbooks-into-Core-Thin-Pairs

Comment: Please mention the important things from the links, due to the risk of links getting broken. Never provide Link-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

another option is to load all your data source in one Master workbook, then write back the result in the same workbook using Reverse Linked Tables.

Now you can use that Master workbook as your backend for all your reports.

or use PowerBI Desktop as your backend, officially it is not support but Excel can have a local connection to PowerBI desktop.

I put more details here
https://datamonkeysite.com/2016/11/13/thin-and-core-workbook-without-sharepoint-or-ssas/